# Eclipse doesn't resolve types

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Juno CDT for a class I am taking, but it is telling me it can't resolve types found in include files, and these aren't headers I wrote.

The program I wrote compiles and runs exactly as it should if I run it through g++ via the command line. The problem is that I can't debug in Eclipse because it doesn't recognize even basic types like string. Also, no code completion. It finds the include files just fine, I can open those and look at the contents, but it still won't resolve types.

I've seen lots of suggestions for people with similar problems, but those all turned out to be not finding the include files, which isn't my problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the types are in a namespace and you're not qualifying them (and not using a using declaration).

Comment: Nope. using namespace std, which is string's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have included the proper directory for the headers themselves.  On my system it is: /usr/include/c++/4.4.6/

However, you probably don't have the directory containing the definition of the macro _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE.  Without this macro definition eclipse does not know that the stl types are in the std namespace.  On my system this macro definition is squirreled away beneath the main c++ dir.  Try adding the following paths to your include list:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux
/usr/include/c++/4.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits
```

If you're not on redhat look for something similar.  You can go to /usr/include and run the following grep to look for the headers with the necessary macro definition:

```
grep -R -P "define\\s*_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE\(" .
```